# sort data in array using parent and child

Tags: javascript

I have this array there is parent and child data

```
  [
    {
        "Id": 40,
        "Name": "Version 1",
        "ParentId": null,

    },
    {
        "Id": 45,
        "Name": "Version 3",
        "ParentId": null,
    },
    {
        "Id": 50,
        "Name": "Version 1.1",
        "ParentId": 40,

    },
    {
        "Id": 56,
        "Name": "Version 2",
        "ParentId": null,
    },
    {
        "Id": 57,
        "Name": "Version 3.1",
        "ParentId": 45,

    },
    {
        "Id": 59,
        "Name": "Version 2.1",
        "ParentId": 56,

    },
    {
        "Id": 77,
        "Name": "Version 3.2",
        "ParentId": 45,
    },
]
```

i want to sort it like this

```
[
    {
        "Id": 40,
        "Name": "Version 1",
        "ParentId": null,

    },
    {
        "Id": 50,
        "Name": "Version 1.1",
        "ParentId": 40,

    },
    {
        "Id": 56,
        "Name": "Version 2",
        "ParentId": null,
    },
    
    {
        "Id": 59,
        "Name": "Version 2.1",
        "ParentId": 56,

    },
    {
        "Id": 45,
        "Name": "Version 3",
        "ParentId": null,
    },
    {
        "Id": 57,
        "Name": "Version 3.1",
        "ParentId": 45,

    },
    {
        "Id": 77,
        "Name": "Version 3.2",
        "ParentId": 45,
    },  
   
]
```

so that first parent will be displayed then their child

Comment: Loop through the array. Push the element to the result, then search the array for their child and push that.

Comment: How many levels deep can the parent/child relationship go?

Comment: @AndrewParks it will be only one level, parent and then all the child

Comment: Why isn't the sorted order `40,50,45,57,77,56,59`?

Comment: @AndrewParks i don't want to sort it with id, i want the first parent then there child then other parent element then there child element, pls check the second array

Comment: I know, but the order of top-level ids in your source data is 40,45,56. In your expected outcome, they are in a different order: 40,56,45. If you only want to ensure the child ids are inserted correctly, why do the parent ids change order?

Comment: @AndrewParks yes in my first data it is like raw data it is mixed (parent and child are mixed and there is no order) now i want to show first parent then there child as in second array

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying. In your original data, first there is 40. Then, the children of 40 need to immediately follow it, so 50 needs to be next. But then, back in your original array, the next entry is 45. So why do you want 56 appearing next instead of 45? The only reason I can see for that is if you want to top-level ids to be sorted by Name

Comment: @AndrewParks 45 id is version 3, first we have to display version 1 which is parent then all the child of version 1 then version 2 then its child then version 3 then its child, is this clarify your doubt what output i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the items by name, to ensure e.g. that the top-level item with name "Version 2" appears before the item named "Version 3". Similarly, this will ensure children are ordered correctly with respect to one another.

Then, starting with the top-level items, flatMap them to their children to get the result.

```js
const data = [{"Id":40,"Name":"Version 1","ParentId":null},{"Id":45,"Name":"Version 3","ParentId":null},{"Id":50,"Name":"Version 1.1","ParentId":40},{"Id":56,"Name":"Version 2","ParentId":null},{"Id":57,"Name":"Version 3.1","ParentId":45},{"Id":59,"Name":"Version 2.1","ParentId":56},{"Id":77,"Name":"Version 3.2","ParentId":45}]

data.sort(({Name:a},{Name:b})=>a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true}))

console.log(data.filter(({ParentId:p})=>p===null)
  .flatMap(e=>[e, ...data.filter(({ParentId:p})=>p===e.Id)]))
```

or, you could just sort by name and that'll automatically order them correctly:

```js
const data = [{"Id":40,"Name":"Version 1","ParentId":null},{"Id":45,"Name":"Version 3","ParentId":null},{"Id":50,"Name":"Version 1.1","ParentId":40},{"Id":56,"Name":"Version 2","ParentId":null},{"Id":57,"Name":"Version 3.1","ParentId":45},{"Id":59,"Name":"Version 2.1","ParentId":56},{"Id":77,"Name":"Version 3.2","ParentId":45}]

console.log(data.sort(({Name:a},{Name:b})=>
  a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})))
```